# Objective-C Variable Declaration Confusion

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I am confused as to why I am allowed to do this (the if statement is to just show scope):

```
int i = 0;
if(true)
{
    float i = 1.1;
}
```

I have a c# background and something like this is not allowed. Basically, the programmer is redeclaring the variable 'i', thus giving 'i' a new meaning. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C (and by extension, in Objective C) it is allowed to declare local variables in the inner scope that would hide variables of the outer scope. You can get rid of `if` and write this:

```
int i = 0;
{
    // Here, the outer i becomes inaccessible
    float i = 1.1;
    {
        int i = 2;
        printf("%d", i); // 2 is printed
    }
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/MOxumP)

C# standard decided against that, probably because it has a high probability of being an error, but C/Objective C does not have a problem with it.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. It helped clear that up. Thanks!

Comment: What @Amin said below -- turn on the "hidden local variables" warning to have the compiler barf on this.   Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on "Hidden local variables" in your build settings to get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You're partially correct, yes, it gives `i` a new meaning, but it's not redeclaring the variable. It's another variable. But since the identifier is the same, the current scope will "hide" the previous, so any use of `i` inside that block refers to the float.

Answer (score 1):

You're not redefining `i`, so much as *shadowing* `i`. This only works when the `i`'s are declared at different levels of scope. C# allows shadowing, but not for `if` statements / `switch` statements, while C/C++/Objective-C allow such shadowing.

After the inner `i` goes out of scope, the identifier `i` will again refer to the `int` version of `i`. So it's not changing what the original `i` refers to. Shadowing a variable is *generally* not something you want to do (unless you're careful, shadowing is likely a mistake, especially for beginners).